# Need Flash / Lightwindow Help Fast

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, lightwindow

I'm trying to finish up a Flash website for my company, and am having some major frustrations with Lightwindow links in Flash. I have a "Videos" page that has a few links, that when you click on one, it opens a Lightbox with a .SWF that plays the video. The problem is that the top of the Lightwindow and the Flash menu bar get in the way of each other, and make everything choppy. And on a PC, my boss couldn't even SEE the 'Close' button on top of lightwindow. The site in question is here, for review:

http://www.facedigitalpost.com/test/

Comment: The site doesn't do anything. It just shows the spinning animation

Comment: It takes about 15 sec to load...

Comment: For me Lightwindow and Menu does not get in the way, however there is no way how to close it and i'm in doubt if I even see anything of Lightbox. There's just bare video window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmode+transparent

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that flash allways is on top. Except for if you make wmode = transparent or opaque.

You set this parameter where you embed your flash.